# What is the difference between .on('click tap') and .on('click || tap')?

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between

```
$('.classname').on('click tap', function(){});
```

and in the second case there is an OR sign ('||') between the events

```
$('.classname').on('click || tap', function(){});
```

Both seem to work fine but I would really like to know if adding an OR sign in the second case makes a difference?

Comment: I think the `||` is just ignored...

Comment: Adding an `OR` sign does not make a difference, it is ignored as @Adjit suggested. It is treated as an event in this case.

Comment: Removed my answer below, due to not realising that "||" can actually be used as the name of an event - although it shouldn't!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`||` is not used as `OR` in jquery binding. It bind custom event named `||`. Which can be triggered by:

```
$('.classname').trigger('||');
```

So, don't use it, if you don't need it.

Answer (score -1):

"event || event" will not work. You can however bind events with "event event", or even state .bind() rather than .on()

Comment: I believe .on is the preferred method since jquery 1.7. http://api.jquery.com/bind/